# Unable to generate request token using Postman

Tags: magento2, oauth, token, request

A request token is a temporary token that the user exchanges for an access token. I am unable to generate a request token using Postman for Adobe Commerce using Consumer Key and Consumer Secret which I generated from the admin site.

- Method used: `POST`
- URL used: `baseURL/oauth/token/request`

I have provided all the request parameters in the Authorization header mentioned in this document [AdobeCommerce Oauth based authentication](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth/#get-a-request-token). Still I am not getting the expected `oauth_token=4cqw0r7v*******xwr0h&oauth_token_secret=rig3x3j*******rr` in the response.

The response I am getting is `oauth_problem=%22oauth_consumer_key%22+is+required.+Enter+and+try+again%2C+%22oauth_signature%22+is+required.+Enter+and+try+again%2C+%22oauth_signature_method%22+is+required.+Enter+and+try+again%2C+%22oauth_nonce%22+is+required.+Enter+and+try+again%2C+%22oauth_timestamp%22+is+required.+Enter+and+try+again`.
However, I have tried putting the Consumer secret also though according to the API Doc it is not mandatory. The response I got, in this case, is `oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired`.

I have used the Signature method HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-SHA256, but the responses are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you already have a request token created in Magento database table `oauth_token`. Clear this table of its entries ,and try.

```
mysql> DELETE FROM oauth_token;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have tried using a new integration i.e. new Consumer Key and Consumer Secret whose OAuth token has not been generated yet. It will be generated once I active the status allowing the module API which can be accessed through the Integration CS, CK. Still, the same errors are being shown.

Comment: what i write in answer , did you see it

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. As it is the client's environment we are not allowed to run any query there. Should we delete all the existing OAuth tokens from the list in order to generate a new OAuth token for a new Integration CK, CS?